# Python: print condition

Tags: python

I found that I just asked the wrong question a few minutes ago, sorry about that. I ran a code that need to identify if the word in certain location matches my condition.

The original code is not in English, I just tried to use a simple way to show you the problem I had. There's actually no space between words in my language, so use split or re is not working.

I need to find the word before "car" to know whether someone loves the car or not. So I used location as conditions to identify it.

For example: (But it will be too long)

```py
message="I do not like cars."

#print(message[14:18])  #cars starts from location 14
location = 14

if message[int(loca)-5:int(loca)-1]=="like":
    print("like")
elif message[int(loca)-8:int(loca)-1]=="dislike":
    print("dislike")
elif message[int(loca)-5:int(loca)-1]=="hate":
    print("hate")
elif message[int(loca)-5:int(loca)-1]=="cool":
    print("cool")
```

I actually used this one in my code, but found that I could not print the word:

```py
if (
    message[int(location) - 5:int(location) - 1] == "like" or
    message[int(location) - 8:int(location) - 1] == "dislike" or
    message[int(location) - 5:int(location) - 1] == "hate" or
    message[int(location) - 5:int(location) - 1] == "cool"
):
    #print "like"
    #unable to do it
```

Is there anyway I can solve it by printing the matching word?

Comment: It's not clear what problem you are trying to solve, but maybe `.split` can help you. `>> "I do not like cars.".split() ; ['I', 'do', 'not', 'like', 'cars.']`

Comment: I think you will need regular expression for this. Look for `re`.

Comment: @DeepSpace I took English code as example, there's no space in sentences in my language.

Comment: What kind of language has no spaces in sentences? :o

Comment: @ToniSredanović Mandarin :)

Comment: You need to provide a relevant example. If you provide an example that doesn't work in your actual use case, you'll get unusable answers.

Comment: @Lara19 Your code is working for me I don't see why it doesn't work for you. Please post the full if you haven't done so.

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi The first code is too long for me, but the second one might not work in this case, so I am trying to find a shorter, simple way to print "like" :)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need Regex:

```
import re

message="I do not dislike cars."
check_list = {"like", "dislike", "hate", "cool"}
pattern = re.compile(r"(\b{}\b)".format("|".join(check_list))) #or re.compile(r"({})".format("|".join(check_list)))


m = pattern.search(message)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))  # --> dislike
```

Comment: "dislike" is longer in this case, so the length will be different :)

Comment: Ok I think I understood what you need .

Comment: Your code is right, but using re cannot solve my problem since there's no space between my words in my language. I just took a bad example I guess.

Comment: `pattern = re.compile(r"({})".format("|".join(check_list)), flags=re.UNICODE)` worked with no space?

Comment: Yes :) But the thing is, car's location is very important in this sentence, I need to find the location of the car first then find if there's matching word in check_list before it.